# How to create TelephonyDisplayInfo object in android R device

Tags: android

I want to get `getOverrideNetworkType()` in android Like as Android CA 5G NSA NR but Enable to Create `TelephonyDisplayInfo`  object to get this. I am using this code but get

```
TelephonyDisplayInfo mTelephonyDisplayInfo;
        mTelephonyDisplayInfo = new TelephonyDisplayInfo(TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
                TelephonyDisplayInfo.OVERRIDE_NETWORK_TYPE_NONE);
```

but get error:-
`TelephonyDisplayInfo()` is not public in `android.telephony.TelephonyDisplayInfo`. Cannot be accessed from outside package this error.

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Google support:

> Although the constructor is public, it's @hide and not a part of the
> API surface, so it shouldn't be accessible to developers. To get the
> TelephonyDisplayInfo, please use
> PhoneStateListener#onDisplayInfoChanged instead. Closing this as
> working as intended.